# Launch app from share button in iOS - Objective C and React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I'm trying to launch MyApp when user selects any image in Photos and taps in Share -> MyApp. 
Now the `(UIView*) shareView` is launched successfully but I need enter to the normal flow in MyApp, I mean, launch all the app with the react native views instead the `shareView`.

```
- (UIView*) shareView {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"src/components/share/share" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Share"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:nil];

  UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
  [myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [myLabel setText:@"THIS IS A LABEL FOR TEST"];
  [rootView addSubview:myLabel];
  rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;


  return rootView;
}
```

(The react native component is not working if is called from here, never is called or rendered)

All the permissions are working and the share button is appearing in the activity action sheet.

I would like to know if this is a impossible task (according the guidelines of apple, the share in activity sheet should be a simple task to send data, maybe using `NSUserDefaults`) but I don't know if programmatically or in life cycle of iOS app this is prohibited.

I try to call the app with `NSURL` and adding the scheme identifier but this is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may talk about the App Sharing Extension. One thing you should know, the extension cannot access the container App’s resource and data directly. If you want share the resource, you must make a App group configuration with both your extension and your container App. Then use the sharing resource space. NSUserDefault and NSFileManager both have the method to access the sharing space. Your code directly accesses the container App’s resource space, not via the sharing space. That’s why you get failed, I think.

Comment: thanks for your answer, we check again and works using the didSelectPost in shareViewController in share extension, the extension scope was the problem. thanks.